# React: render component from within function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there some way to make the following to work? I want to pass "welcome" to the onClick event for example and it should render a component with that name to specified DIV. I would like it to be dynamically named, but I can settle for switch(index) :)

```
var Menu = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        // do something
    },
    menuClick: function(index) {
        render(
            <{index} />,
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <span>
                <span className="menuLink" onClick={this.menuClick.bind(this, "welcome")}>Home</span>&nbsp;
                <span className="menuLink" onClick={this.menuClick.bind(this, "management")} >Generator Management</span>&nbsp;
                <span className="menuLink" onClick={this.menuClick.bind(this, "about")}>About Us</span>
            </span>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure about how you are calling `render` in the `menuClick` function.  Looks like you potentially need to structure this as 2-3 different components.

Comment: If `"welcome"` is selected, what would you like `<{index} />,` to render?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes. I have components welcome, management,... and I would like to render those to the "content" div.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to *not* use JSX in this case:

```
menuClick: function(index) {
        render(
            React.createElement(index, null, ''),
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    },
```

Comment: this actually makes nothing , I get an error "render is not defined".  If I add React. before render, the content div gets empty once I click on something. I have the Welcome and other menu-referenced components working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`state`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) of the component to do this

```
    var Menu = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          data: [],
          message: null
        };
      },
      componentDidMount: function() {
        // do something
      },
      menuClick: function(index) {
        this.setState({
          message: index
        });
      },

      getText: function() {
        if (this.state.message) {
          return (
            <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
          );
        }
        return null;
      }

      render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <span>
              <span className="menuLink" onClick={this.menuClick.bind(this, "welcome")}>Home</span>&nbsp;
              <span className="menuLink" onClick={this.menuClick.bind(this, "management")} >Generator Management</span>&nbsp;
              <span className="menuLink" onClick={this.menuClick.bind(this, "about")}>About Us</span>
            </span>
            {this.getText()}
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: does this render the component named message?

Comment: No it changes the `state` and renders html based on that.

You could replace `{this.getText()}` with `<message title={this.state.message} />`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), it's made especially for those purposes.